# What is the best way to import UI Modules/Components lazily

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am currently following the recommended Module structured layed out in the Angular [ngModule docs](https://angular.io/guide/module-types).

My understanding is that the Shared Module should generally contain any Directives, Guards, Models and other helper functionality that will be used throughout the app. Which then most other modules will import this Shared Module to implement this general functionality.

Most examples I've seen will then also import all the UI Modules into the Shared Modules. So for example if I am using Angular Material, I will import all the shared UI modules here ie. MatInputModule, MatSelectModule, ...

My question is if I want to load modules lazily to reduce initial bundle size, and assuming some UI Modules are only used in one Feature Module. Would it then makes sense to rather only import this UI Module into the Feature Module, and not the Shared Module.

For example. If my Auth Module is the only module that uses the MatCardModule, should I then rather only import it into the Auth Module, instead of with all my other imported MatModules in the Shared Module?

Assuming the answer is yes - would it still make sense if MatCardModule is used in two different Feature Module (you'd then have it imported into two separate modules)? Does Angular handle this cleverly - for example if the module has already been dowloaded in the one lazy loaded module, it wont download again for the second lazy loaded module?

**TLDR** Is it better to import only the UIModules you need into your Feature Modules (even if it means you'll be importing the same UIModule multiple times), or is it better to keep all you UIModules imported in the Shared Module, and then just import the Shared Module in all your other Feature Modules

Answer (score 0):

This is IMO baed on my experience

I have a shared module which as you mentioned I add all of my shared component and directives there.

I create a Module called MyCommonModule and import and export Material modules and other 3rd party modules which is used in most of the modules 
Then I import MyCommonModule in AppModule

Also there are some specific modules that will be used in some of the feature modules, for example ChartModule, you can import that one specifically.

About bundle size if you don't use a module even if you imported Angular will not include that via TreeShaking phase, so even if you import all the size of js file will be as much as the modules you already used application wide

And about your second equation if a module js file is already downloaded angular won't download it again